# Highlight the text in webview when figer moves over the text in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, selection, highlight

I want to highlight the text when I drag the finger over the text in webview. I am able to detect the gesture and the coordinates at the point touched, but I am not able to highlight the text when I drag my finger over the text.

Any sample codes would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do it by using JS.

For example, try http://www.jqtouch.com/, detect touch and change CSS Properties :-)

It's the best way I have in mind.

Comment: @Vincent--> can you provide me any sample code which implemented this, it would me more helpful.Thanks.

Comment: Sorry But I don't have the time to code it ^^ I think there are differents ways to do it. For example you could wrap each words with a <span>, <div> or anything else. Then you could set a css class when the span is touched ;)

Comment: When i drag my finger over webview which method will be called.Is there any delegate method called ?

Comment: You can subview the UIWebView but the best way is really to use JS in your case. Or you can do it without WebView but it'll be more difficult (like in the dragon ditaction app).

Comment: Hey warrior,u got any solution pertaining to this question?